# Validate optional or nullish method

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I have a problem with how to validate these fields in my schema:

```
 const schema = z.object({
 
  spzNumber: z
    .string()
    .trim()
    .regex(/^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}[A-Za-z]{2}$/)
    .optional(),
  vinNumber: z.string().trim().min(17).max(17).optional(),
})
```

I'm using react-hook-form for my input fields. And if I leave an empty field it still gives me an error according to Zod schema.

I searched for the solution and found one [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/310#issuecomment-794533682) that works but in a weird way.

When I do this:

```
spzNumber: z
    .string()
    .trim()
    .regex(/^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}[A-Za-z]{2}$/)
    .optional()
    .or(z.literal('')),
```

in my schema, it worked. But when I submit the form and send data to the database I don't have a null value in DB but 5 empty strings. Why is that, and how to work around it?

Comment: It sounds like your form is passing in an empty string rather than `null`. Zod will only validate the shape of the data, so if the form were passing in `undefined` or `null` then it would validate, but because it's passing in the empty string it fails the regex test and the check for `undefined` or `null`. The version that is working for you seems to be because it's tacking on a literal check to allow `''` through. That value now validates and is passed along with your request. The fix would be to check for the empty string in the value coming from the form and to convert that to `null`.